# Redialing a PPPOE connection programmatically

Tags: pppoe

I have a PPPOE connection on a computer. That computer has two LAN cards and I activated ICS on it. The problem is, the connection kinda degrades over time (don't know why), and a redial would be nice, hourly maybe. I was thinking of writing an AutoIT script that would do this, if, for example I'm sending some data to a port the gateway pc is listening on. The only trouble is, I don't know what's the name of the executable I would have to run.

EDIT: I'm interested in the one with the GUI.

EDIT 2: I am interested in automating this process, and wouldn't like to have to write the thing in AutoIT (this a last resort option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use rasdial (which is build in into windows) and create a batch script (.bat extension) like so:

```
rasdial connectionname
```

-or-

if you want to do it in a programming language, you can just call the command internally

C# example:

```
public static int OpenConnection(string connectionName, int Timeout) {
   int ExitCode;
   ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
   Process Process;

   ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C rasdial " + connectionName);
   ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
   ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
   Process.WaitForExit(Timeout);
   ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
   Process.Close();

   return ExitCode;
}
```

and I guess your desired language will have something like this available as well.

oh and you can use:

```
rasdial "connection name" /d
```

to drop the connection.

Comment: Will this have the same effect as with using the GUI ? Will the icon with the "computers" appear in the taskbar ?

Comment: I cannot test this right now, but I believe that the "connected" icon will indeed be visible in the taskbar, just as the other "network icons" are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make something for yourself with [rasdial](http://webtools.live2support.com/windows/rasdial.php) and [at](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)?